# Debug CoffeeScript with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm starting a fresh web project and the last part of my configuration is to enable debugging for my CoffeeScripts files.

The whole project is build using a Grunt task that compile coffee to js and generates the proper map file but I cannot make the Coffeescript debuging work in IntelliJ.

Note that I don't want to use IntelliJ File Watchers.

Here is my Gruntfile :

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
    coffee:
      options:
        sourceMap: true
      files:
        expand: true
        flatten: true
        cwd: 'src/'
        src: ['**/*.coffee']
        dest: 'src/'
        ext: '.js'
    concat:
      option:
        separator: ';'
      dist:
        src: ['src/**/*.js']
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name%>.js'
    uglify:
      options:
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> v<%= pkg.version%> by Pierre Degand <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
      dist:
        files:
          'lib/<%= pkg.name%>.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
    watch:
      files: ['<%= coffee.files.src %>']
      tasks: ['coffee', 'concat', 'uglify']

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch')

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['coffee', 'concat', 'uglify'])
```

My Simple CoffeeScript file (Break point is on line 2 on IntelliJ) :

```
name = 'Pierre'
console.log "Hello #{name} !"
```

Generated JS file from Grunt :

```
(function() {
  var name;

  name = 'Pierre';

  console.log("Hello " + name + " !!");

}).call(this);

/*
//@ sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
*/
```

The source map

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "app.js",
  "sourceRoot": "",
  "sources": [
    "app.coffee"
  ],
  "names": [],
  "mappings": "AAAA;CAAA,GAAA,EAAA;;CAAA,CAAA,CAAO,CAAP,IAAA;;CAAA,CACA,CAAA,CAAa,CAAb,EAAO,CAAM;CADb"
}
```

And finally the html I use to test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="src/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I used File watchers, the .js and the .map.js were subfiles of the .coffee file, can I achieve the same behavior without using File Watchers ?

If I right-click/"Debug index.html" in IntelliJ, I can read "Hello Pierre!!" in my IntelliJ debuger console, but the script is not breaked on the `console.log()`

Did someone had same troubles ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> When I used File watchers, the .js and the .map.js were subfiles of the .coffee file, can I achieve the same behavior without using File Watchers?

No, you can't. This is a file watchers feature

> If I right-click/"Debug index.html" in IntelliJ, I can read "Hello Pierre!!" in my IntelliJ debuger console, but the script is not breaked on the console.log()

This works for me if I refresh a page in browser after the code was executed. Please vote for [this ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6413)